# Advice for WCF with WP7

Tags: wcf, windows-phone

I have a WP7 app that requires most of its pages to retrieve data from a WCF service. Basically to start using WCF I need to do this:-

```
ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();
```

after finish ...

```
client.close();
```

I don't think it is right to create an object of the *ServiceClient* in every page but only in App(). So, I am wondering when and where it is right to call `client.close()` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually up to you, it's you who needs to decide on the instance management policy of your client and services. This is a design concern of the whole solution you're trying to achieve. There are 3 service instance management policies:

- Per Call Services
- Per Session Services
- Singleton Services

But what you are talking about is actually using a singleton of your client. I would suggest you would avoid that. Whenever possible, stick to Per Call instance management, which is what you are doing at the moment. Try to close the connection with the service as soon as you can, unless you have a good reason to do things differently.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally speaking you should close the client immediately you are done with it. This frees up the connection you have made to the server. If you have parallel or synchronous (one after another, continuous) calls, you can use same object, otherwise close connection as you finish with it.

Hope this answers your question.